# OpenBSD - run several X servers at a time

Tags: openbsd

I if install an OpenBSD 6.2, how can I run several X servers at a time?

Purpose: have 2 "X servers" running

Why?: one "X" would be used for general purposes, the other "X" would be used only for the Firefox. To have a more correct separation, if someone breaks the actual webbrowser.

Switching to the other "X" server would be with CTRL+ALT+F* ?

Comment: You can also use ``Xnest``

Answer (score 0):

Good news: It is technically possible.

Bad news: It does not work under Xenocara (OpenBSD X11 clone) with out of DRI/KMS (kernel video driver) (X access hardware using `/dev/xf86` in this case) but works on XOrg with Linux and FreeBSD. You can try if it works in your case. If you are using KMS then it will probably work.

Good news again: you do not need it because it does not increase security: web browser is X client: it runs as any regular process and uses X to display data.

*X and virtual terminals*.

PC video hardware is under control of OpenBSD console driver `wscons` which provides several virtual terminals (`vt`). When X launches, it borrows `vt` from `wscons` and from than moment it controls video by itself using its driver (directly using `/dev/xf86` or using KMS driver in kernel). Keyboard control is also moved from `wscons` to X, so when you push CTRL+ALT+F* X asks `wscons` to switch to another `vt` and `wscons` gets video and keyboard back. So, you can have to X running on two different `vt`s. 
X has an option `vtXX` to choose `vt` to borrow. Since running X with out of client makes no sense, you could do

```
 DISPLAY=:2 xinit xterm -- vt1 :2
```

Everything after `--` is passed to X, so X will start on vt1. You then switch to the different `vt` and run

```
 DISPLAY=:3 xinit xterm -- vt3 :3
```

You now have 2 X servers. If it works, you can them configure your display manager (`xenodm` on OpenBSD) to pass `vtXX` option to `X`.

*X, its clients and why there is no reason to run 2 X servers*.

X client (be it `xterm` or `firefox`) uses `DISPLAY` environment variable to find its `X` server, connects to it and uses it to display data and read keystrokes.

So, client runs locally, it just uses different X servers to display data. Once your client hacked -- it does not matter which X server it is connected to.

PS: This is why Xenocara does not run on 2 different vts when using `vesa(4)` driver: it uses `/dev/xf86` (aka `option APERTURE`)(`xf86(4)`) to access video memory and it sets lock on this device file. So, it may work with KMS